# Spark: where is the UUID() function in Scala?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

SparkSQL has the [`uuid()` SQL built-in function](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/#uuid). However, I couldn't find it in Scala to use with the Dataset API.

Surely, we can just go with:

```scala
expr("uuid()")
```

And it will work properly since it will be parsed as an expression.

Do we have it in the Scala Dataset API? Where? If not, is there any important technical reason why not?

Thanks.

---

Bonus question: Do we have it in the python API? Where?

Comment: You have `java.util.UUID.randomUUID()`

Comment: sure I have and surely can write a non-deterministic udf for it. But why if they already implemented it, and I can benefit from catalyst?

Answer (score 0):

If you take a look at Spark source code for [org.apache.spark.sql.functions](https://%20https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/branch-3.3/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/functions.scala), `uuid` functions is missing here, so you can't use it via calling a scala function in dataset/dataframe api.
So for now you have a few options:

- `expr("uuid()")` - as you mentioned above
- `val generateUUID = udf(() => java.util.UUID.randomUUID().toString)` - use UDF

Comment: for option 2 should be a good idea to define it as non deterministic udf